# Magento 2 GraphQL - Cart Query Getting Error

Tags: magento2, graphql, magento-graphql

In GraphQL when I running below queries getting error.

**Mutation :**

```
mutation customerAccessTokenCreate {
  generateCustomerToken(
    email: "test@test.com",
    password: "Test@123"
  ) {
    token
  }
}


{
  customerCart {
    id
    items {
      id
      product {
        name
        sku
      }
      quantity
    }
  }
}
```

**Query :**

```
{
    cart(cart_id: "dmCaKmh6zzm4KDSMSOGGkS75sB071857") {
    email
        shipping_addresses {
          available_shipping_methods {
            amount {
              currency
              value
            }
          }
        }   
    }
}
```

**Error :**

```
{
    "messages": {
        "error": [
            {
                "code": 500,
                "message": "Fatal Error: 'Allowed memory size of 792723456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 67108872 bytes)' in '/var/www/html/m2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Select.php' on line 1004",
                "trace": "Trace is not available."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209976/magento-2-2-2-allowed-memory-size-of-792723456-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-alloc

Comment: Already tried above solutions but not luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The above query are define in this file : **vendor/magento/module-quote-graph-ql/etc/schema.graphqls**

> You need to debug this file code: **vendor/magento/module-quote-graph-ql/Model/Resolver/ShippingAddress/AvailableShippingMethods.php**

[image]

**You need to check the code line by line. After debugging the code, you can find it. Otherwise please provide steps to reproduce the issue. In my case, All default queries and mutations are working fine. And If you did some customization, please share your code so I can check.**

**Note: The Customer Tokens are added on Header**:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/364509/82670

**[Update Answer]**

> **I created a customer's token using the below mutation.**

[image]

> **Added customer token into header**

[image]

> **Run customer cart query and get customer cart id.**

[image]

> **I run a cart query to show available shipping methods. without product in the cart. It returns null.**

[image]

> **Using the customer cart id I added one product to the cart.**

[image]

> **After I run the cart query again and the shipping method is visible.**

[image]

**All queries and mutations are working well. All are tested on Magento 2.4.6-p1**

**Module List: app/etc/config.php**

```
<?php
return [
    'modules' => [
        'Magento_Store' => 1,
        'Magento_Config' => 1,
        'Magento_AdminAnalytics' => 1,
        'Magento_AdminNotification' => 1,
        'Magento_AdobeIms' => 1,
        'Magento_AdobeImsApi' => 1,
        'Magento_AdobeStockAdminUi' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaGallery' => 1,
        'Magento_AdobeStockAssetApi' => 1,
        'Magento_AdobeStockClient' => 1,
        'Magento_AdobeStockClientApi' => 1,
        'Magento_AdobeStockImage' => 1,
        'Magento_Directory' => 1,
        'Magento_AdobeStockImageApi' => 1,
        'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport' => 1,
        'Magento_Theme' => 1,
        'Magento_Amqp' => 1,
        'Magento_Backend' => 1,
        'Magento_User' => 1,
        'Magento_Authorization' => 1,
        'Magento_Eav' => 1,
        'Magento_Customer' => 1,
        'Magento_AdminAdobeIms' => 1,
        'Magento_Backup' => 1,
        'Magento_Indexer' => 1,
        'Magento_GraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_BundleImportExport' => 1,
        'Magento_Variable' => 1,
        'Magento_CacheInvalidate' => 1,
        'Magento_Cms' => 1,
        'Magento_Catalog' => 1,
        'Magento_Rule' => 1,
        'Magento_Security' => 1,
        'Magento_CmsGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_EavGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_Search' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogImportExport' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogRule' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogInventory' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogPageBuilderAnalytics' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogSearch' => 1,
        'Magento_Msrp' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogRuleGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_Quote' => 1,
        'Magento_Bundle' => 1,
        'Magento_SalesSequence' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite' => 1,
        'Magento_StoreGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaStorage' => 1,
        'Magento_Payment' => 1,
        'Magento_Sales' => 1,
        'Magento_CheckoutAgreementsGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaGalleryUi' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_CmsPageBuilderAnalytics' => 1,
        'Magento_Downloadable' => 1,
        'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite' => 1,
        'Magento_CmsUrlRewriteGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_CompareListGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_Integration' => 1,
        'Magento_Checkout' => 1,
        'Magento_UrlRewrite' => 1,
        'Magento_QuoteGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_ConfigurableProduct' => 1,
        'Magento_Tax' => 1,
        'Magento_Contact' => 1,
        'Magento_Cookie' => 1,
        'Magento_Cron' => 1,
        'Magento_Csp' => 1,
        'Magento_Widget' => 1,
        'Magento_Robots' => 1,
        'Magento_Analytics' => 1,
        'Magento_DownloadableGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_CustomerGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_CustomerImportExport' => 1,
        'Magento_SampleData' => 1,
        'Magento_Deploy' => 1,
        'Magento_Developer' => 1,
        'Magento_Dhl' => 1,
        'Magento_AdvancedSearch' => 1,
        'Magento_DirectoryGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_GroupedProduct' => 1,
        'Magento_CustomerDownloadableGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_ImportExport' => 1,
        'Magento_Weee' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogSampleData' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogCustomerGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_Elasticsearch' => 1,
        'Magento_Elasticsearch7' => 1,
        'Magento_Email' => 1,
        'Magento_EncryptionKey' => 1,
        'Magento_Fedex' => 1,
        'Magento_GiftMessage' => 1,
        'Magento_GiftMessageGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_GoogleAdwords' => 1,
        'Magento_GoogleAnalytics' => 1,
        'Magento_GoogleGtag' => 1,
        'Magento_Ui' => 1,
        'Magento_GoogleShoppingAds' => 1,
        'Magento_BundleGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_PageCache' => 1,
        'Magento_GroupedCatalogInventory' => 1,
        'Magento_GroupedImportExport' => 1,
        'Magento_BundleSampleData' => 1,
        'Magento_GroupedProductGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable' => 1,
        'Magento_DownloadableImportExport' => 1,
        'Magento_CardinalCommerce' => 1,
        'Magento_InstantPurchase' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogAnalytics' => 1,
        'Magento_Inventory' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryAdminUi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryAdvancedCheckout' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryApi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryBundleImportExport' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryBundleProduct' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryBundleProductIndexer' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryCatalog' => 1,
        'Magento_InventorySales' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryCatalogApi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryCatalogFrontendUi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryCatalogSearchBundleProduct' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryCatalogSearchConfigurableProduct' => 1,
        'Magento_ConfigurableProductGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductFrontendUi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryConfiguration' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryElasticsearch' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryExportStockApi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryIndexer' => 1,
        'Magento_InventorySalesApi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryImportExport' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupApi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupAdminUi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryInStorePickup' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_Shipping' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingApi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuoteGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSales' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesApi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuote' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShipping' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingAdminUi' => 1,
        'Magento_Multishipping' => 1,
        'Magento_Webapi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryCache' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification' => 1,
        'Magento_Reports' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryProductAlert' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryQuoteGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryRequisitionList' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryReservations' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryReservationCli' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryReservationsApi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryExportStock' => 1,
        'Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_InventorySalesAsyncOrder' => 1,
        'Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryShipping' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventorySourceSelection' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend' => 1,
        'Magento_InventorySwatchesFrontendUi' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryVisualMerchandiser' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryWishlist' => 1,
        'Magento_JwtFrameworkAdapter' => 1,
        'Magento_JwtUserToken' => 1,
        'Magento_LayeredNavigation' => 1,
        'Magento_LoginAsCustomer' => 1,
        'Magento_LoginAsCustomerAdminUi' => 1,
        'Magento_LoginAsCustomerApi' => 1,
        'Magento_LoginAsCustomerAssistance' => 1,
        'Magento_LoginAsCustomerFrontendUi' => 1,
        'Magento_LoginAsCustomerGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_LoginAsCustomerLog' => 1,
        'Magento_LoginAsCustomerPageCache' => 1,
        'Magento_LoginAsCustomerQuote' => 1,
        'Magento_LoginAsCustomerSales' => 1,
        'Magento_Marketplace' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaContent' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaContentApi' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaContentCatalog' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaContentCms' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaContentSynchronization' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaContentSynchronizationApi' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaContentSynchronizationCatalog' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaContentSynchronizationCms' => 1,
        'Magento_AdobeStockAsset' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaGalleryApi' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaGalleryCatalog' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaGalleryCatalogIntegration' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaGalleryCatalogUi' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaGalleryCmsUi' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaGalleryIntegration' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaGalleryMetadata' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaGalleryMetadataApi' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaGalleryRenditions' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaGalleryRenditionsApi' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaGallerySynchronization' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaGallerySynchronizationApi' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaGallerySynchronizationMetadata' => 1,
        'Magento_AdobeStockImageAdminUi' => 1,
        'Magento_MediaGalleryUiApi' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogWidget' => 1,
        'Magento_MessageQueue' => 1,
        'Magento_GroupedProductSampleData' => 1,
        'Magento_MsrpConfigurableProduct' => 1,
        'Magento_MsrpGroupedProduct' => 1,
        'Magento_DownloadableSampleData' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupMultishipping' => 1,
        'Magento_MysqlMq' => 1,
        'Magento_NewRelicReporting' => 1,
        'Magento_Newsletter' => 1,
        'Magento_NewsletterGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_OfflinePayments' => 1,
        'Magento_SalesRule' => 1,
        'Magento_OfflineShipping' => 1,
        'Magento_OpenSearch' => 1,
        'Magento_Sitemap' => 1,
        'Magento_PageBuilder' => 1,
        'Magento_PageBuilderAnalytics' => 1,
        'Magento_GraphQlCache' => 1,
        'Magento_ThemeSampleData' => 1,
        'Magento_PaymentGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_Vault' => 1,
        'Magento_Captcha' => 1,
        'Magento_Paypal' => 1,
        'Magento_Persistent' => 1,
        'Magento_ProductAlert' => 1,
        'Magento_ConfigurableSampleData' => 1,
        'Magento_ProductVideo' => 1,
        'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport' => 1,
        'Magento_QuoteAnalytics' => 1,
        'Magento_QuoteBundleOptions' => 1,
        'Magento_QuoteConfigurableOptions' => 1,
        'Magento_QuoteDownloadableLinks' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaAdminUi' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaCheckout' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaCheckoutSalesRule' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaContact' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaCustomer' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaMigration' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaNewsletter' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaPaypal' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaReview' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaSendFriend' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaStorePickup' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaUi' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaUser' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaValidation' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaValidationApi' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaVersion2Checkbox' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaVersion2Invisible' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaVersion3Invisible' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaWebapiApi' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaWebapiGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaWebapiRest' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaWebapiUi' => 1,
        'Magento_RelatedProductGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_ReleaseNotification' => 1,
        'Magento_RemoteStorage' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi' => 1,
        'Magento_RequireJs' => 1,
        'Magento_Review' => 1,
        'Magento_ReviewAnalytics' => 1,
        'Magento_ReviewGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_ReviewSampleData' => 1,
        'Magento_AwsS3' => 1,
        'Magento_Rss' => 1,
        'Magento_PageBuilderAdminAnalytics' => 1,
        'Magento_PaypalCaptcha' => 1,
        'Magento_SalesAnalytics' => 1,
        'Magento_SalesGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_SalesInventory' => 1,
        'Magento_OfflineShippingSampleData' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogRuleSampleData' => 1,
        'Magento_TaxSampleData' => 1,
        'Magento_CheckoutAgreements' => 1,
        'Magento_SalesRuleSampleData' => 1,
        'Magento_UrlRewriteGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_CustomerAnalytics' => 1,
        'Magento_Securitytxt' => 1,
        'Magento_SendFriend' => 1,
        'Magento_SendFriendGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesAdminUi' => 1,
        'Magento_AwsS3PageBuilder' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogCmsGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_Swagger' => 1,
        'Magento_SwaggerWebapi' => 1,
        'Magento_SwaggerWebapiAsync' => 1,
        'Magento_Swatches' => 1,
        'Magento_SwatchesGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation' => 1,
        'Magento_SwatchesSampleData' => 1,
        'Magento_MsrpSampleData' => 1,
        'Magento_TaxGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_TaxImportExport' => 1,
        'Magento_CustomerSampleData' => 1,
        'Magento_TwoFactorAuth' => 0,
        'Magento_ThemeGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_CmsSampleData' => 1,
        'Magento_Translation' => 1,
        'Magento_AdminAdobeImsTwoFactorAuth' => 0,
        'Magento_GoogleOptimizer' => 1,
        'Magento_Ups' => 1,
        'Magento_SalesSampleData' => 1,
        'Magento_CatalogUrlRewriteGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_AsynchronousOperations' => 1,
        'Magento_Usps' => 1,
        'Magento_ConfigurableProductSales' => 1,
        'Magento_PaypalGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_VaultGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_Version' => 1,
        'Magento_InventoryInStorePickupWebapiExtension' => 1,
        'Magento_WebapiAsync' => 1,
        'Magento_WebapiSecurity' => 1,
        'Magento_ProductLinksSampleData' => 1,
        'Magento_WeeeGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_CurrencySymbol' => 1,
        'Magento_WidgetSampleData' => 1,
        'Magento_Wishlist' => 1,
        'Magento_WishlistAnalytics' => 1,
        'Magento_WishlistGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_WishlistSampleData' => 1,
        'PayPal_Braintree' => 1,
        'PayPal_BraintreeGraphQl' => 1,
        'Temando_ShippingRemover' => 1
    ]
];
```

Comment: Can you check in fresh instance, I am getting error in fresh instance also.

Comment: please provide the steps to reproduce it and which magento version are using.

Comment: 1. First Get Customer Token, 2 Next Pass Authorization Bearer Token in Customer Cart 3. Pass Authorization Bearer Token and id in Third Query (Cart Query) .

Comment: Please Update your question with steps. and also provide which magento version are using. Is there any third-party module or not?

Comment: Fresh Instance Not installed any custom modules/themes.

Comment: Which Magento Version?

Comment: Latest Magento 2.4.6-p1

Comment: I will install and update you.

Comment: @VrajeshPatel I updated the answer. I did not find any error with the Fresh installation. May be https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/graphql/usage/authorization-tokens/#session-cookies or something wrong with your magento. Please try to install again using the new db with sample data.

Comment: @VrajeshPatel have you checked?

Comment: It's due to db issue - in some of the order having issue.